# Validate DRF response against OpenApi 3 .yml schema

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I've specified API schema in a file called `apidocs.yml` using OpenApi 3 specifications. Now I want to validate Django-rest-framework API response against that particular .yml schema.

How do I go about doing that? I've searched on google and couldn't find any libraries capable of doing that. The closest I've found was a library called [flex](https://github.com/pipermerriam/flex) but it only supports `OpenApi version 2`.

Is there a python packaged that could validate `json` response from API against OpenApi 3 .yml schema file?

Comment: Something like `openapi-spec-validator` https://github.com/p1c2u/openapi-spec-validator ?

Comment: I have the same question. The accepted answer relies on an external tool. I am looking to validate the response everytime the response is served. Is there a way to validate the response against OpenAPI spec v3 defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am testing with [dredd](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd), which defines itself:

> Dredd is a language-agnostic command-line tool for validating API description document against backend implementation of the API.

Although OpenAPI v3 is partially supported.